# get property not defined

Tags: angular, httpclient

newbie question. What is wrong with this code below? This fails saying get property TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

```
  var http: HttpClient;
  const req = http.get<any>(url)
      .subscribe(
      res => {
```

Comment: http variable is not defined

Comment: var http: HttpClient; is not right?

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

  @Injectable()
    export class Example {
      constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

      getExample(){
        return this.http.get<any>(url)
          .subscribe(
          res => {};
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

first inject HttpClient in your constructor and then you can use it like this.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export abstract class DataService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  public get<T>(url: string, params?: any): Observable<T> {
    return this.http.get<T>(url, {headers: headers, params: params});
  }
}
```

or

```
const req =this.http.get<any>(url)
      .subscribe(
      res => {
```